# SQL : Count the number of occurrences occuring on output column and calculate some percentage based on the occurences

Tags: mysql, sql

My sql query fetches list of bug fix verification for a firmware for e.g. def-456 is a ticket which asks me to test firmware test on a product. def-456 has several sub-tasks where results are being recorded. Results are recorded as :id:  abc-123, abc-124, abc-125 etc (as shown in table below). These corresponding id's have "pass" or "fail" result. I need to calculate two values ---->
1. Number of attempts : in following example number of attempts would be 3/5 , there are 3 pass and 2 fail (i.e. pass/pass+fail) , here  i can use count() method however don't know how to append "/5" and 
2. 1st attempt success rate : in following example, abc-123 failed however abc-124 passed, abc-125 failed however abc-126 passed and abc-127 passed without any failure, means my success rate is : 1 out 3 (i.e. 1/3), how can I display these values in sql? this is bit tricky and I am not able to find logic for this.

Here is my data for def-456:

```
    value | id| 
    --------------
    fail | abc-123  
    pass | abc-124   
    fail | abc-125   
    pass | abc-126   
    pass | abc-127
```

and here is o/p I am trying to display :

```
id   |   value | attempts| %for attempts  | 1st attempt
----------------------------------------------------
abc-123    fail |   3/5  | 60%              | 1/3
abc-124    pass |   3/5  | 60%              | 1/3
abc-125    fail |   3/5  | 60%              | 1/3
abc-126    pass |   3/5  | 60%              | 1/3
abc-127    pass |   3/5  | 60%              | 1/3
```

Comment: What query/queries have you tried already?

Comment: hi hunter : here is my attempt: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02a26/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you need:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.resolution,
    b.*
FROM 
    Table1 a
CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            CONCAT(SUM(aa.resolution = 'pass'), '/', COUNT(*)) AS attempts,
            CONCAT((SUM(aa.resolution = 'pass') / COUNT(*)) * 100, '%') AS percent_attempts,
            CONCAT(SUM(bb.mindate IS NOT NULL AND resolution = 'pass'), '/', SUM(resolution = 'pass')) AS first_attempt 
        FROM
            Table1 aa
        LEFT JOIN 
            (
                SELECT 
                    MIN(`date`) AS mindate 
                FROM 
                    Table1
            ) bb ON aa.`date` = bb.mindate
    ) b
```

[SQLFiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02a26/39/0)

Comment: Thanks Zane for posting comments. In your posted code resolution is pass, fail, fail, fail , fail, pass . Logic for calculating first time success rate is : if code encounters pass on very first row counter is 1, then if it encounters fail keep counter 1, after a fail if it encounters pass still counter should be 1, however if there is pass after previous pass then counter  should be 2. In above eg. success rate is 1st time success rate is : 1/6