# SQL : Count occurences of values in sql table efficiently

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL : Count the number of occurences occuring on output column and calculate some percentage based on the occurences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301083/sql-count-the-number-of-occurences-occuring-on-output-column-and-calculate-som)

Here is url for test data / table : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56ffd4/1

My table generates o/p for following table :

```
(id,       resolution) 
('abc-123', 'fail'),
('abc-456', 'pass'),
('abc-789', 'pass'),
('abc-799', 'fail'),
('abc-800', 'pass'),
('abc-900', 'pass');
```

my script o/p is :

```
id          RESOLUTION  TS              @PREV   C   RES
abc-123     fail    July, 02 2012         1     1   -
abc-456     pass    July, 02 2012         2     0   50.00%
abc-789     pass    July, 02 2012         1     0   100.00%
abc-799     fail    July, 02 2012         1     1   -
abc-800     pass    July, 02 2012         2     0   50.00%
abc-900     pass    July, 02 2012         0     0   100.00%
```

here is o/p script:

```
SELECT st.*, 
       @prev:=@counter + 1,
       @counter:= CASE 
         WHEN st.resolution = 'pass'
         THEN 0
         ELSE @counter + 1
       END c,
       CASE WHEN @counter = 0 
            THEN CONCAT(FORMAT(100/@prev, 2), '%') 
            ELSE '-' 
       END res
  FROM so_test st, (SELECT @counter:=0) sc
```

I need to append two columns to above output table to count occurrences for passing and fail values as:

```
id          RESOLUTION  TS              @PREV   C            fail   pass
    abc-123     fail    July, 02 2012         1     1   -        1
    abc-456     pass    July, 02 2012         2     0   50.00%          1
    abc-789     pass    July, 02 2012         1     0   100.00%         1
    abc-799     fail    July, 02 2012         1     1   -        1
    abc-800     pass    July, 02 2012         2     0   50.00%          1
    abc-900     pass    July, 02 2012         0     0   100.00%         1
```

Comment: And what is your question? What you need to get as a result?

Comment: I need to append two columns of "fail" and "pass" , i.e. count unique occurrences

Comment: according to your query - you know how to use `CASE WHEN`. Why not use it as you do it for `RESOLUTION` column?

Comment: I am bit confused, can you please guide on how to use it for resolution.

Comment: You ask about 'counts' but don't show zeroes for the counts.  The data you show above only has one record per ID value, so the counting is trivial.  However, if you intend the data to have, say, 5 records for a single ID, 4 of them showing 'fail' and one showing 'pass', then you have a lot more work to do, but you need to explain this in the question (and illustrate).  While it is possible to map zero counts to NULL, it is hardly nice to look at in the SQL (though there are worse travesties committed daily).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you just want the pass and fail columns at the end of the output table as you've specified then put a comma after

```
END res
```

and add the following after it:

```
CASE WHEN st.resolution = 'fail'
            THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
END fail,
CASE WHEN st.resolution = 'pass'
            THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
END pass
```

Not sure what the blank is in your columns but I've just set them as NULL.